# How to add and enable swagger-ui config in docker?

Tags: docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to get configure the a docker-compose deployed swagger-ui with config options so as to enable the requestSnippets option.
My docker-compose service:

```yaml
---
version: '3.8'
services:
  swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    container_name: swagger
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON_URL: "http://localhost:8083/services/rest/swagger.json"
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger-config.yaml:/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger-config.yaml
```

The config I'm trying to load: (Taken from the [github doc page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#display))

```yaml
---
requestSnippetsEnabled: true
requestSnippets: >
  {
    generators: {
      curl_bash: {
        title: "cURL (bash)",
        syntax: "bash"
      },
      curl_powershell: {
        title: "cURL (PowerShell)",
        syntax: "powershell"
      },
      curl_cmd: {
        title: "cURL (CMD)",
        syntax: "bash"
      },
    },
    defaultExpanded: true,
    languages: [ "curl_bash", "curl_powershell", "curl_cmd" ]
  }
```

Has anyone attempted swagger config in this way who can enlighten me as to what I am missing?
Thanks.